# How to get max length of a number of strings at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-functions, fold

(Update: I am programming for microcontrollers, so I am short of memory and computation power. Therefore I am limited to C-strings.)

I have a number of strings and want to find the maximum length of them and assign this to a constexpr variable. I came across this approach:

```
template <uint32_t N>
constexpr uint32_t get_string_length (const char (&str) [N])
{
  return N;
}

template <uint32_t... N>
constexpr uint32_t max_string_length_all (const char (&... strs) [N])
{
  constexpr uint32_t lengths [] = {get_string_length (strs)...};
  uint32_t max_len              = 0;
  for (uint32_t len : lengths)
  {
    if (len > max_len)
    {
      max_len = len;
    }
  }
  return max_len;
}
```

And this should be called like:

```
inline char const my_string_0 [] = "my string 0"; // several of these with different string lengths
constexpr uint32_t max = max_string_length_all (my_string_0, my_string_1, my_string_3);
```

But I get

`error: 'strs#0' is not a constant expression`

in the first line of `max_string_length_all` (also for strs#1 and strs#2)
I use GCC set to C++ 17. I am not familiar with variadic functions and fold expressions so I don't know how to fix it.

In case it can be solved the next step would be:

```
  typedef struct
  {
    char const * my_string;
    // other struct members
  } T_my_struct;
  T_my_struct my_array []
  = {
      {my_string_0, /*other data*/},
      {my_string_1, /*other data*/},
      // more
    };
```

Now pass `my_array` to something like `max_string_length_all` and again get the maximum string length out at compile time.
Is that possible ?

Comment: The answer to your second question is no, `char const * my_string` doesn't have any length so won't work

Comment: Using `constexpr` variable inside `constexpr` function seems suspicious. `my_string_0` is not `constexpr`... Why don't you just use `std::string_view`?, it is fully `constexpr` and AFAIK would solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, `my_string_0` has no size property to it. You need to use a `constexpr`-aware string representation that also stores string size. The `std::string` itself has `constexpr` methods since C++20. If the strings are based on fixed literals and don’t need any compile-time pre-processing, maybe a `std::string_view` will do:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

namespace {

constexpr std::string_view A{"blah"};
constexpr std::string_view B{"foo"};
constexpr std::string_view C{"something"};

template <typename... Strings>
constexpr size_t max_size(const Strings&... strings) {
  return std::max({strings.size()...});
}

constexpr size_t MAX{max_size(A, B, C)};

}  // namespace

int main() {
  std::array<char, MAX> chars{'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g'};
  for (char c : chars) std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. One thing I forgot to mention. I am programming for microcontrollers, so I am short of memory and computation power. Therefore I am limited to C-strings. I will update my question.

Comment: Meanwhile I discovered something else: I can well do sizeof (my_string_0) and get the right result at compile time. Could this be used in a constexpr function?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.
Finally I found a way to do it myself: (without variadic functions and fold)

```
inline char const my_string_0 [] = "my string 0"; // several of these with different string lengths
typedef struct
  {
    char const * my_string;
    int32_t length;
    // other struct members
  } T_my_struct;
  T_my_struct my_array []
  = {
      {my_string_0, sizeof (my_string_0), /*other data*/},
      {my_string_1, sizeof (my_string_1), /*other data*/},
      // more
    };

inline constexpr uint32_t array_size = sizeof (my_array) / sizeof (T_my_struct);

constexpr int32_t max_string_length_all (void)
{
  int32_t max_length = 0;
  for (uint32_t idx = 0; idx < array_size; idx++)
  {
    if (my_array [idx].length > max_length)
    {
      max_length = my_array [idx].length;
    }
  }
  return (max_length);
}
constexpr uint32_t max_str_length = max_string_length_all ();
```

Works fine for me with gcc C++17.